# Downgrading from PHP 7 to PHP 5 on a Docker Server

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, virtualhost, php-7

I'm currently doing testing so we can migrate some old WordPress sites to a new server that will use PHP 7.  I have a Docker environment prepared that matches this set up.  (I'm testing several WP sites on two containers -- a PHP 7 one and a MySQL 5.7 one on an Nginx server).

So far everything is going fine but one of the sites I'm testing is so outdated that its WordPress version is totally incompatible with PHP 7. ( In the wp-settings.php file there's tons new object references [for example: `$wp_the_query =& new WP_Query();`] that now [cause fatal errors in PHP7](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.other.new-by-ref).)

I'd like to revert briefly to PHP 5, update WordPress on that site and go back to using PHP 7.

The setup I'm using is [php7-dockerized](https://github.com/hamptonpaulk/php7-dockerized).  There's a blog post about it [here](https://medium.com/code-school/setting-up-a-local-php7-development-environment-with-docker-compose-e9531baed291#.4hv3eguea).

I used `docker-compose down`. Then I did a ham-fisted edit of the dockerfile to use php 5 versions of things instead of PHP 7. Then I ran  `docker-compose up` I expected to find terrible errors. Instead it just kept using PHP 7 like nothing happened.  What do I do?

I should note I'm open to other suggestions on how to fix this.  The version of WordPress used is allegedly v 3.1.2. I think it may be older.

Here is my Frankenstein Dockerfile.  [Here's a link to the original.](https://github.com/hamptonpaulk/php7-dockerized/blob/master/Dockerfile)

```
FROM nginx

# Remove default nginx configs.
RUN rm -f /etc/nginx/conf.d/*

# Install PHP 7 Repo

# This is Stephanie. This is a massive mistake. I am attempting to get this docker file to run PHP 5.

# COMMENTING OUT PHP 7 LINES
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -my wget
# RUN sh -c "echo 'deb http://packages.dotdeb.org jessie all' >> /etc/apt/sources.list"
# RUN sh -c "echo 'deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org jessie all' >> /etc/apt/sources.list"
# RUN wget https://www.dotdeb.org/dotdeb.gpg -O - | apt-key add -
# RUN wget https://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.key -O - | apt-key add -

# Install Packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -my \
  supervisor \
  curl \
#  php7.0-curl \
#  php7.0-fpm \
#  php7.0-mysql \
#  php7.0-mcrypt \
#  php7.0-sqlite \
#  php7.0-xdebug \
#  php7.0-mbstring \
  php5-curl \
  php5-fpm \
  php5-mysql \
  php5-mcrypt \
  php5-sqlite \
  php5-xdebug \
  php5-mbstring \
  php-apc

# Ensure that PHP7 FPM is run as root.
RUN sed -i "s/user = www-data/user = root/" /etc/php/5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
RUN sed -i "s/group = www-data/group = root/" /etc/php/5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf

# Prevent PHP Warning: 'xdebug' already loaded. XDebug loaded with the core
RUN sed -i '/.*xdebug.so$/s/^/;/' /etc/php/5/mods-available/xdebug.ini

# Add configuration files
COPY conf/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/
COPY conf/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/
COPY conf/php.ini /etc/php/5/fpm/conf.d/40-custom.ini
COPY conf/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

Thank you!

Comment: Step 1: Go to https://phpdocker.io/ and go to the generator page. Here you can generate docker files for pretty much any PHP set up. Job done, and no messing around hand-writing the docker files.

Comment: @Spudley I appreciate the help but I needed finer control over the docker file as I already had a MySQL container loaded up that had a lot of data on it that need to work with the PHP container.  I ended up just updating WP on my local apache server (running PHP 5.6) then pasting into the /www/ folder on my nginx server.  :/ Not the way I would've liked to solve it but it's done. Thank you!